# I have issues with multi-instances of a class with class attributes

Tags: python, scapy, class-method, class-attributes

This post is actually an edit of an old post because the previous one wasn't clear at all on my issue.

I think I have issues regarding what's really going on when you create instances of classes that heritates from another class and share a same attribute.

I have a piece of code, which uses the library Packet from scapy.packets. Its prupose is to create a header, a data layer, combine those two to form a packet.

I decided to create two classes Header and Layer which both heritate from Packet and therefor share the class attribute **fields_desc**. In these two classes I added two **classmethods** in order to add some fields to my soon-to-be packet. I then create an instance of my header, an instance of my layer and combine these two packets to form the final packet :

```py
class Init:
    class Header(Packet):
        name = "RESM_header"
        fields_desc = []
        @classmethod
        def add_IntField(cls, name, value):
            cls.fields_desc.append(IntField(name, value))

        @classmethod
        def reset(cls):
            """
            Allows for the fields_desc to be set to []
            """
            cls.fields_desc=[]

    class Layer(Packet):
        name = "DATA"
        fields_desc = []

        @classmethod
        def add_IntField(cls, name, value):
            cls.fields_desc.append(IntField(name, value))

        @classmethod
        def reset(cls):
            """
            Allows for the fields_desc to be set to []
            """
            cls.fields_desc = []
```

If I then want to create a header with the field "id" I will use :

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Init.Header.add_IntField("id",4) # adds the requested field with its value
    a = Init.Header() # creates the packet with the fields_desc already filled
```

If I show the packet I have the result :

```py
a.show() 
###[ RESM_header ]### 
  id        = 4
```

However, in my overall project, I have to create several **different** headers. I would like for instance to reset the fields_desc of my header with `python a.reset()` and then add a new field with `python Init.Header.add_IntField("id",6)`with a new value.

However the value of my id is still the previous value. The following code returns the same packet twice :

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Init.Header.add_IntField("id",4)
    a = Init.Header()
    a.show()
    a.reset()
    Init.Header.add_IntField("id",5)
    a = Init.Header()
    a.show()
    a.reset()
```

Even weirder, if i decide to create another field different than the previous one, the code goes brrrr with several errors :

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Init.Header.add_IntField("id",4)
    a = Init.Header()
    a.show()
    a.reset()
    Init.Header.add_IntField("another_field",5)  # try to create another field
    a = Init.Header()
    a.show()
    a.reset()
```

returns the error :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/IVS_NG/Tests/DebugTest.py", line 46, in <module>
    a.show()
  File "D:\Users\T0267246-A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 1464, in show
    return self._show_or_dump(dump, indent, lvl, label_lvl)
  File "D:\Users\T0267246-A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 1414, in _show_or_dump
    fvalue = self.getfieldval(f.name)
  File "D:\Users\T0267246-A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 411, in getfieldval
    return self.payload.getfieldval(attr)
  File "D:\Users\T0267246-A\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 1824, in getfieldval
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: another_field
```

If anyone has an idea of what's going on I'd be very grateful !
Cheers

Comment: Why do you want to use class methods instead of good old fashioned instance methods?

Comment: I tried but if instead of classmethods i do create simple methods, and if I create an instance : ```a = Init.Header(); a.add_Intfield("id", 4)``` then for some reason a is not even a packet regarding to the scapy library.

Usually after calling my classmethods, and after creating the instance, a is in the forme of a scapy packet ```b'x00\x00\..' ```.

But with simple methods, a is juste of type ```<Header  |>```

Comment: I don't know scapy, so I'm hesitant to make a judgment here, but from skimming [the documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html) it looks to me like you're not quite using the package the way it's intended to be used. But, as I said, I'm no expert, nor do I know what you're trying to accomplish, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Can you try and tell me how you think it is supposed to be implemented ? The way I see it, the class Packet has an attribute name and a field_desc (and many more attributes but which are not relevent to me right now)
By creating an instance of the class Packet, with a given field_desc and a name I think it is meant to creat a packet containing the fields and the name you gave.

the nature of the object resulting from the instance is a scapy packet imo

Comment: I guess it would help to know what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to build a set of packets that correspond to a certain message

for in stance let's say I have the MessageA. This message has a header and a data layer. The header layer is the same for every message except for the id field that indicates which message it is. For instance here the header would contain a IntField for the msg_data_length, and an IntField for the msg_id.

Comment: To create such header I would have to add to my field_desc these two fields initalized with their values. The data layer can have several fields (could be Intfield, ShortField, ShortEnumField etc, they're all ine the scapy.packets). These field could be about anything (say for instance the name of a file). TO create the data layer the same goes on I add these fields to the field_desc and I creta an instance of the class Init.Layer which is then the layer packet. I then combine the header and tha layer to have the final packet. Then I start over again but with a new message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna post this as an answer because it wouldn't fit in the comments. I'm no expert on scapy, so I don't know if this'll do what you need, but after having skimmed the docs it appears to me that it isn't designed to dynamically change the fields like you're trying to do. Instead, you should define all the fields up front, and then you can set the values per instance. For example, your `Header` class might look like this:

```
class Header(Packet):
   name = "RESM_header"
   fields_desc = [ IntField("id", 0) ] # define a field called "id" with default 0
```

And that's it, really. Now you can create a `Header` instance with any id you want like this:

```
header = Header(id = 12345) # pass the desired id to the constructor here
header.show()
# ###[ RESM_header ]###
#   id        = 12345
```

If you need `Header` to have another field, just add it to the `fields_desc` list statically:

```
class Header(Packet):
   name = "RESM_header"
   fields_desc = [ IntField("id", 0),
                   IntField("another_field", 0) ]
```

And create your instance like before:

```
header = Header(id = 12345, another_field = 69)
header.show()
# ###[ RESM_header ]###
#   id        = 12345
#   another_field= 69
```

Answer (score -1):

try this in your child class

```
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

https://realpython.com/python-super/

Comment: Do you mean sth like :

```python
class Init:
    class Header(Packet):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Init.Header, self).__init__()
``` 

? I'm just afraid that when I call my classmethods it adds fields in the field_desc but when i create my object ```a = Init.Header()``` it goes through the constructor of Packets which will set back fields_desc to []

Comment: So I implemented the ```super(Init.Header).__init__()``` and ```super(Init.Layer).__init__()``` but either ways, the second time I create my object ```a = Init.Header()``` with a different field, the same error appears